# Composer: How to require one dependency OR another

Tags: php, composer-php

My code works fine with PHP >= 5.3.0 but it also works fine with HHVM >= 3.0.0.
How I can define that in composer.json?

The following means you have to run PHP *and* HHVM on the same process which is simply impossible:

```
"reqire": {
    "php": ">=5.3",
    "hhvm": ">=3.0"
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, your composer.json should require only PHP version because that is "at the core" of your library/project/whatever.

If you really want to point out that your code can run under hhvm, I guess you could create a separate "dummy" project `mabe/hhvm-ready` for example and add it under "suggest" in your main project with a comment `This library can run under HHVM.` or `This library is HHVM ready.`.

Or you could print an informational message after your library has been installed from a [script](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md).